# Loading a file into an array

Tags: php

Very new to PHP and ran into some trouble and was wondering if anyone could help. I'm having problems with an array of names that are looked up in a database. When I use just the array of names it gets processed correctly. When I try and read a file of those same names only the last name gets displayed. My question is how can I get all names displayed for the file array?

Please see examples and code below. Thanks for your time.

```
//This works -- Sample 1
$x = array("joe", "paul", "tom");

//This does not -- Sample 2
$x = file("name.txt"); //Same names from the array above are in this file
```

Here is the full code below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Name Check</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx");
            if (!$con) {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            mysql_select_db("xxxxxxxxxx", $con);

            // $x=array("joe", "paul", "tom"); //displays all names correctly in Sample 1 below
            $x = file("name.txt"); // only displays the last name in the file. Sample 2 below

            foreach ($x as $test) {
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE Name='$test' Limit 0, 1");

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo $row['Name'];
                    echo " " . $row['Sport'];
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            }
        ?> 
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Sample 1 output**

```
joe basketball
paul basketball
tom baseball
```

**Sample 2 output**

```
tom baseball
```

---

Here is the contents of name.txt, that was requested. Thanks!

```
joe 
paul 
tom
```

Comment: Could you provide sample file contents?

Comment: post the format of the file please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file()` leaves in the newline character at the end of each line, which only the last one lacks. You could use `rtrim($test)` to fix this.

You should also be escaping the name in case it contains characters like `'`, so a complete solution would be (just before the query):

`$test = mysql_real_escape_string(rtrim($test));`